# Thread 1 Error on VC push?

Tags: swift, segue

My app currently has 3 VCs. The rootVC modally presents the second VC via UIButton--which works fine--but I'm having trouble getting the third VC appear after a UILabel tap in the second VC.

This is the code in the SecondVC that handles the tap:

```
var goToStats : UILabel {
        var label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 300, height: 60)
        label.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y + 250)
        label.text = "Statistical Breakdown"
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 30)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor(
                displayP3Red: 1/255,
                green: 102.0/255,
                blue: 102.0/255,
                alpha: 1)
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        label.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap)))
        return label
        }

    view.addSubview(goToStats)
}

@objc func handleTap() {
    print("Tapped!")

    let thirdVC = ThirdVC()
    self.navigationController!.present(thirdVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Upon running, I get the following error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om8Fx.png)

Is there any explanation? I thought maybe there is no navigation Controller associated with the second VC (since it's returning nil), but the VC itself sits on a navigational stack, so I don't think that's the case here. Is it a problem with my third VC? Here is the current code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class thirdVC : ViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
```

}

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It appears that `SecondVC` is not in a navigation controller or `statsViewController` is `nil`. Don't you mean to present `thirdVC`?

Comment: statsViewController is a typo, sorry! I meant to replace it with thirdVC to make the code more readable. The root VC is definitely in a navigation controller because I used the same code to present the secondVC. Does that automatically make the second VC a navigational controller? Sorry I'm really new to all of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rootViewController` could be a `navigationController` but when you `present` something like this,

```
let secondVC = SecondVC()
self.navigationController!.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This doesn't mean that `SecondVC` will have a `navigationController`. To have a `navigationController` for `SecondVC`, you need to embed this `ViewController` inside a `navigationController` as below,

```
let secondVC = SecondVC()
let secondNavC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
self.navigationController!.present(secondNavC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now, if you will present `ThirdVC` as below from `SecondVC` then it will work

```
let thirdVC = ThirdVC()
self.navigationController!.present(thirdVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you haven't embedded second `ViewController` inside a `UINavigationController`, then you will get that crash because you are force unwrapping(`!`) the `navigationController` which is not available in second `ViewController`.

Comment: oh hey again! This question was ages back but thanks. So, if I'm understanding correctly, every VC needs to be embedded in it's own UINC? That seems to be at odds with the purpose of a NC in the first place. I'm doing this all programmtically, so that might change things, but whenever I see people handle multiple VCs it seems like they only have one NC. Or does it have to do with modall presentation? Like every VC that is presented modally needs to be in it's on NC if there are additional VCs

Comment: Yes this requirement is only valid for modal presentations. For push you don’t really need to embed every viewcontroller.